# Symfony ZipArchive PHP Extension Class Not Found

Tags: php, symfony, php-extension, php-ziparchive

I tried this code

```
var_dump(class_exists('ZipArchive'));
$zip = new ZipArchive();
```

well, the output is like this.

```
bool(true)
Fatal error: Class 'MyProject\ProjectBundle\Controller\ZipArchive' not found in \path\to\my\Controller.php on line 83
```

Anyone can help me how to solve this?
I have installed

```
php-pear
php5-dev
libcurl3-openssl-dev
libevent-dev
pecl-http
all i need have been installed
and i have put the extension to my php.ini then restart my apache
```

But i still get that error.
Then I tried this

```
$z = new /ZipArchive();
```

from this [page](http://symfony2forum.org/threads/98-ZipArchive()-wtf-!-!)

and then i got this error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in /path/to/my/symfonyController.php on line 83
```

Comment: Where did you save your class?  It doesn't look like you saved it in the right place

Comment: umm, i have found the answer.. Adding `use ZipArchive` after the namespace.. and then `$z = new ZipArchive();`

Comment: Just calling `new ZipArchive()` looks for a class `ZipArchive` in the local directory. You had the right idea with the `new /ZipArchive()` except that **you have the slash the wrong way around**, you should actually be using `new \ZipArchive()` (the slash takes it to the global namespace).

Comment: Thanks for your comment.. I have try that too, but it doesnt work.. Umm, but now i have found the way and it works..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After installation is done and check your ZipArchive class is exist with this code

```
var_dump(class_exists('ZipArchive'));
```

if it returns `true` then you just add

```
use ZipArchive;
```

put it after your namespace
and then put this code

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
```

on where you are want to put.

Answer (score 2):

You need to refer to ziparchive and then use the call $Z. To refer you have to add `use ZipArchive` before the new line